# Segmentation Fault During The lsearch in C

Tags: c

```
      #include<stdio.h>
      #include<string.h>
      #include<stdlib.h>

      void* lsearch(int* key,int* base,int count,int elemSize){
              int i = 0;
              for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
                      void* elemAddr = (base + (i * elemSize));
                      if(memcmp(key,elemAddr,elemSize) == 0){
                              return elemAddr;
                      }
              }
              return NULL;
      }

      int main(){
              int a[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60};
              int key = a[2];
              printf("\n sizeof(a) : %d \n",sizeof(a));
              int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
              printf("\n size : %d \n",size);
              int* search = lsearch(&key,a,size,sizeof(int));
              printf("\n search : %d \n",*search);
              return 0;
      }
```

Getting a segmentation fault, dunno why the for loop is looping till the count and returns a NULL, since the key 30 is present in the array a[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void* lsearch(int* key,int* base,int count,int elemSize){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
    void* elemAddr = (base + (i * elemSize));
```

The problem is how you are assigning `elemAddr`... you're compensating for the size of each element as well as the index, but you're dealing with `int *` data so standard pointer math already does this compensation for you; you therefore double compensate.

```
    void* elemAddr = (base + i);
```

is what you want.

Alternatively you could change the type of `base` to be a `void *` which would require you to do the compensation you're already doing.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't do what you think it's doing:

```
void* elemAddr = (base + (i * elemSize));
```

The way pointer arithmetic works, adding a value to a pointer actually adds that value *times the base datatype size* to the pointer.  You don't have to do it yourself.  So this will do what you want:

```
void* elemAddr = base + i;
```

Actually, there's really no need to use `memcmp` here.  You have an array of `int` and an `int` value to compare against, so just do that directly:

```
for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
    if (*key == base[i]) {    
        return &base[i];
    }
}
```